# How to select a certain value in various rows and transfer it into a new column?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(vehicle1 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), vehicle2 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No"), vehicle3 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), vehicle4 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No"), vehicle5 = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), vehicle6 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No")), row.names = c(NA, -25L), .Label = c("Yes", "No"
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to create a new column and fill with "Yes" and "No" based on a condition.

The condition is: If there is a "Yes" in a row fill the cell of the new column with "Yes".
If there is no "Yes" in a row fill the cell of the new column with "No".

It does not matter if there are more than one "Yes" in a row.

Does somebody has an answer to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R solution is using `ifelse()` + `rowSums()`, i.e.,

```
ifelse(rowSums(df == "Yes")>0,"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple ways to do this. One approach using `rowSums`

```
df$New_col <- c("No", "Yes")[(rowSums(df == "Yes") > 0) + 1]
```

---

However, in this case, as we only have `"Yes"` and `"No"` values in the dataframe and since `"Yes"` is greater than `"No"` (`"Yes" > "No"`) a short and efficient approach would be to use use `pmax`.

```
df$New_col <- do.call(pmax, df)
```

If you have `NA`'s use :

```
df$New_col <- do.call(pmax, c(df, na.rm  =TRUE))
```